# pointer declared out of scope error

Tags: c++

```
    if (moveTicker > 0) {
    delete playerLoc;
}
moveTicker++;
QGraphicsEllipseItem * playerLoc = scene2->addEllipse(locaytion.getLocation(0),locaytion.getLocation(1),5,5,QPen(Qt::black),QBrush(Qt::black));
```

When comiler gets to this is says that playerLoc is called out of scope, i get that because it is supposedly called after the if statement, but the if statement wont run until the playerLoc has been declared so the error becomes comfusing. Is there any good way to create the new player location and then delete the old one after new one is created.

Comment: The problem is not the assignment, it is the *declaration*.  Put `QGraphicsEllipseItem * playerLoc;` before it is first referenced.

Comment: wont that create a problem with creating *playerLoc again on the last line.

Comment: Declare it before the block where the `delete` is in, then don't redeclare it in the last line, just define it (scrap the `QGraphics... *`).

Comment: Another problem, everytime I call the function wont it be redeclared before it had been deleted?

Comment: And, it would be deleted in some cases before it reaches the point where is is assigned causing some error i dont know, undefined behavior maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i create this function so it
>   creates a new object, under same pointer, but deletes old object?

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem * playerLoc = /* ... first declaration and definition */
if (moveTicker > 0) {
    delete playerLoc;
}
moveTicker++;
playerLoc = scene2->addEllipse(locaytion.getLocation(0),locaytion.getLocation(1),5,5,QPen(Qt::black),QBrush(Qt::black));
// you can just redefine it
```

But since you program C++, and if I understand your goal right, I would strongly advice you looking into classes and encapsulation.

Comment: ever re iteratioin though would a new playerLoc be made, or would it error out? or would the first declaration override the previous first declaration.

Comment: And, if its deleted before it reaches the final line, i would be redifining a variable that doesnt exist anymore

Comment: if i didnt delete the pointer and just redefined it, would the previous definition just dissapear? Answer: Nope.

Comment: @Tibblist it delete's the *data* the pointer points to, not the pointer itself. The pointer can be redefined to point to any data as long as it matches the data type.

Comment: @Tibblist Look into RAII and create a class if you want a function with persistent data. But it would be the best to read a good book about C++.

Comment: Does anyone who knows QT, know if the scene has to be a pointer, will it work as a object?

Comment: I have run this solution, when running it when it hits delete, it creates undefined behavior, or as QT puts it segfault

Comment: @Tibblist That's a topic for a new question which also requires to see a bit more of your code.

Comment: now its not segfaulting but it wont delete the previously created ellipses

Comment: @AdamS dude you have copied my answer also this will cause a crash if the condition is true.

Comment: @MoKi Sorry, I haven't read your answer, I just answered the comment from under it with the code provided in the original question. This won't help much anyway because it seems the questioner lacks basic C++ understanding and would rather need a book, or a really thorough explanation...

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your description properly you want to make `playerLoc`to point to a new object. you don't need to delete the pointer for this purpose just define it again for example `playerLoc = scene2->addEllipse(locaytion.getLocation(0),locaytion.getLocation(1),5,5,QPen(Qt::black),QBrush(Qt::black));`of course the function `addEllipse` must return a pointer with the same type.

Comment: I want to delete the old one though, before or after creating the new one, doesnt matter as long as the old ellipse is gone and the new one is there

Comment: when you use `delete playerLoc;` your object is deleted but your pointer is not and it becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: @MoKi it would clarify things to post the whole function

Comment: @MoKi this is basically my question how do i create this function so it creates a new object, under same pointer, but deletes old object

Comment: just create an object instead of a pointer. then redefine it whenever needed this will replace the old one with the new one at the same memory location that has been already assigned to it. do you really need to use a pointer?

Comment: for example `int a;` then `a = 1` and whenever you need to change the value of a just do `a = 2` and if you need to use functions that accept a pointer in their arguments just use `&a`

Comment: to make me able to help you more i need you to post more of your source code because from what you have posted it's really difficult to guess the meaning and type of your variables and pointers. please update the question description.